# Print several plots on one PDF page in R

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I am trying to plot 4 graphs on one single PDF page.  Untill now, the only output I got was 1 file per page. I would like to have all of them on one page. One plot is stocked in "c", the three others are produced using a loop. Here is the code I use :

```
pdf("path_to_file.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
plot(c)
for (exp in expL) {
  plot(plot_list[[exp]])
}
dev.off
```

I tried without the "onefile" specification, or adding :

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
```

or even

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
```

but nothing helps...

I would be grateful for some help.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`c` should be same type of plot as expL.

If they are, do:

```
library(cowplot)
plot_grid( append( list(c), expL ), nrow=2 )
```

Comment: expL and c were both produced using ggplot/geom_bar if it is was you meant. I do not really understand how to use "plot_list( append( list(c), expL ) )". I get an error output telling me thath "plot_list" is not a function

Comment: I used because you had it in your code. changed it to something that does exist.